# Iscroll is very slow on android 4.1 device

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I am Developing A phone gap application here i am using iscroll4 to scroll the fixed list item 
It's working fine in all other device but creating problem on "Android 4.1 Version device" the Scrolling is very slow. Please can You give me any solution for that its sroll fine on Android 4.1 device.

My Cade is Like This..

```
  var myScroll = new iScroll('headerWrapper',{
            snap: 'li',
            hScrollbar: false,
            vScrollbar: false ,
            momentum: true,
            vScroll: false,
            onScrollMove : function(e){
 if(deviceType() == 'android'){
                    var deviceVersion = device.version;

                    console.log(" deviceType is ===>>"+deviceVersion);
                    if(deviceVersion=='4.1' || deviceVersion=='4.1.1'|| deviceVersion=='4.1.2'){
                        console.log("android version is ===>>"+deviceVersion);
                     setTimeout(function(){
                        myScroll.refresh(); }, 1000);
                    }
                }
               // setTimeout(function(){myScroll.refresh();},0);
                }
    });
```

Comment: Android 4.1 should support CSS overflow scrolling. Do you really need to use iScroll on such devices? Consider using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-testallprops-css_overflow_scrolling) to detect if overflow scrolling is supported so you could setup CSS scrolling instead of iScroll.

Comment: yes it's support overflow auto but in my application i am using iscroll it's needed so please if you have solution with iscroll than tell me.